# Kafka stream count distinct in scala?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to do a distinct count per user in a kafka stream. This is my initial implementation but has the error on aggregate

```
Required: [Seq[String], mutableHashSet[String]]
Found: mutable.HashSet[String]
```

and I'm not sure how to provide a custom serde for `mutable.HashSet` either ...

```
val totalUniqueCategoriesCounts: KTable[String, Int] = inputStream
    .filter((_ , ev) => ev.eventData.evData.pageType.isDefined)
    .groupBy((_, ev) => ev.eventData.custData.customerUid.get)
    .aggregate(initializer = mutable.HashSet[String])(
      (aggKey: String, newValue: Event, aggValue: mutable.HashSet[String]) => {
        val cat: String = newValue.eventData.cntData.contentCategory.get
        aggValue += cat
        aggValue
      }, **Serde Here?**)
    .mapValues((set: mutable.HashSet[String]) => set.size)
    //.count()
  totalUniqueCategoriesCounts.toStream.to("total_unique_categories")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm also concerned about performance. Is this the best way to do a count distinct in a kafka stream?

**Update** Fixed the code issue but still concerned about the performance implications of this (if any) or any better ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all I was forgetting was the `()` after `mutable.HashSet[String]`, so instead it should be

```
val totalUniqueCategoriesCounts: KTable[String, Int] = inputStream
    .filter((_ , ev) => ev.eventData.evData.pageType.isDefined)
    .groupBy((_, ev) => ev.eventData.custData.customerUid.get)
    .aggregate(initializer = mutable.HashSet[String]())(
      (aggKey: String, newValue: Event, aggValue: mutable.HashSet[String]) => {
        val cat: String = newValue.eventData.cntData.contentCategory.get
        aggValue += cat
        aggValue
      })
    .mapValues((set: mutable.HashSet[String]) => set.size)
    //.count()
  totalUniqueCategoriesCounts.toStream.to("total_unique_categories")
```

Intellij was totally throwing me off :/

The performance question still remains and would really appreciate any input.